# Testing values with & 1<<0?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I am new when it comes to bit-wise operations and I stumbled across something interesting. Assume the following:

```
unsigned char A;
unsigned char B;

if(A & 1 << 0){
    //testing
}
```

Why is it always required to have `variable & 1<<0`? 
Is there a case when this is not required? 
Suppose we have:

```
unsigned char temp;
temp = ~A & ~B;
```

and we are looking to test out temp. What is the difference when testing temp by itself vs testing only bit 0 with `temp & 1<<0`?

Thanks!

Comment: who told you it must be done that way?

Comment: It is never required, I would rather discourage this. It is pointless and makes your code less intelligible. If you want to check oddity of your variable then just test `x & 1`

Comment: `1 << 0` is sometimes used for code consistency, when testing multiple bits, e. g. `if(A & 1 << 0){/*foo*/} else if(A & 1 << 1){/*bar*}`. When you write each test on a new line, the tests can look more consistent.

Comment: understand that what you've shown is UB since none of your variables are initialized.

Comment: @yano it's clearly a pseudo code example, he is not asking about the result of the test, but if the shift left is needed. `A` and `B` being undefined/defined doesn't change a thing. Stop nitpicking.

Comment: @Geoffrey looks like real code to me. I wasn't nitpicking, just anticipating the next problem and offering a friendly warning. Sorry it upset you so.

Comment: Note: `A & 1 << 0` is  like `A & (1 << 0)` and not `(A & 1) << 0`.

Comment: "Why is it always required to have variable & 1<<0?" --> That premise is incorrect.  It is not required to have the `<<0`.

Comment: I see, so it is not mandatory to use `1 << 0` (I knew it had no apparent effect). I never assumed it might just be consistency. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1<<0` is pointless, shifting 1 left zero bits has no effect.

`1<<0 == 1`

The below would work identical

```
unsigned char A;
unsigned char B;

if(A & 1){
    //testing
}
```

It's the single `&` that makes this a bit-wise operation, not the shift left (`<<`) operation

If you wanted to test bit 7 for example, you could go about it two ways:

```
if (A & 128) {
```

or

```
if (A & (1<<7)) {
```

In the case of the latter since it's using constant values the compiler would simply distil this down to `128` and avoid the `shl` entirely, so it's entirely up to you which you would like to use depending on the code and your coding style.

Comment: This is a great example! Thank you,sir!